# Can I take both branches at the end?

Tags: defenders-quest

I've gotten to the point where I can either do the mission `The Way Out` or `Following Zelemir`. I would really love to 3-star *all* the levels. When I take one branch, can I still complete the other branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you can!  The branches don't disappear when you choose one, even when you get all the way to the end.  After completing one branch, the game will save, and the second branch will still be available.